como puedo hacer reverse proxy en nginx para que mi dominio se va sin el puerto?
He visto varios tutoriales sobre nginx para instalarlo en linux , en especial este
https://wiki.almalinux.org/series/nginx/NginxSeriesA02R92.html#%F0%9F%93%9D-installation-instructions
donde la gente lo instala para poder mostrar un sitio web y donde hay dos benditas (si, benditas) carpetas sites-available y sites-enabled que no se encuentran al instalar el nginx.
La cosa es que cuando instalo usando su guia para alma linux 9 no se crean e
intento crearlas para poder ingresar los archivos de configuracion en ellos para luego importarlos en el archivo nginx.config pero no funciona la configuracion
siempre mi sitio se ve
dominio.com:3000/resultados
en lugar de
dominio.com/resultados
En otro tutorial vi que en la carpeta config.d hay un archivo default que no existe , que segun debe colocarle un enlace simbólico a la carpeta de los sitios habilitados o (sites-enabled)
para poder lograr hacer funcionar me dicen en otros tutoriales que cree un archivo y lo ingrese en la carpeta default.d y procedo a crearlo
midominio.conf y eso es lo que contiene:
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name midominio.com www.midominio.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header REMOTE-HOST $remote_addr;
        add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
        proxy_send_timeout 30s;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

y esta se importa en el archivo nginx.config
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
esto lo hace antes de que use el puerto 80 en su configuracion
hice los cambios y reinicié el servidor pero sigue sin mostrarse el dominio sin el puerto pero no he tenido éxito aún
la aplicación es node js , usa el puerto 3000 y se usa pm2

tienes que usar hostvirtuales y mesclar nginx con apache ...

En principio Nginx, no tiene proxy reverse, pero se puede hacer una "simulación". En principio, creo que vale con los parámetros que has puesto, pero te dejo este post por si no lo has visto:
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Por favor, incluye la parte relevante de la información como parte de tu respuesta. Esto es importante porque, si mañana ese vínculo se rompe, la información dejaría de estar disponible. Está bien dejar links a material de apoyo y documentación, pero en general, las respuestas que tienen solo links se consideran de baja calidad. Te invito a leer [answer].
